# webkit transform: translateZ(0) breaks all div s with postion fixed

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, positioning, fixed, background-position

I have problem with fixed background as its not rendering right in chrome 40/webkit, and after some search I found adding

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

fixes that, however that will break any div with

```
position:fixed;
```

Here is an example shows that the div is not fixed anymore, however the background renders just fine in the example even if translateZ(0) removed! which doesn't happen in my case.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hbj5b6e/7/

works fine on IE, Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-webkit-perspective: 0;` instead of `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`.

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matijamrkaic/3hLnfqg8/).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work :/. there is something wrong I cant seems to spot! this is the website sweedy.com.au on chrome I made the background on "scroll" to get over the rendering problem. the problem will appear as soon as it changed to "fixed".

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); can fix the background but will break the fixed menu
-webkit-perspective: 0; do nothing :\